# Struts 2 empty string action

Tags: java, forms, struts2

Using Struts2, does an empty string in action do anything when a  is submittefd
How would this form get posted?

```
<s:form action="" method="POST" namespace="mynamespace" onSubmit="return false;"></s:form>
```

Comment: this form never get posted unless you turn off javascript in the browser or override the event. Better if you change the code to let the form being submitted even if you didn't specify the action name in the action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

W3 specification for HTML5 very clearly mentions that

> The action and formaction content attributes, if specified, must have
>   a value that is a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by
>   spaces.

Here's the reference:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formaction

However, if you do write `action=""`, depending upon the browser, you'll mostly end up submitting the form to the same action you are on.